# Unknown Protocol exception while using url.openConnection()

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

I am using the following line to create `HttpsUrlConnection` in Android.

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

It works on most Android devices. Strangely on some Android devices, this line of code does not return HttpsUrlConnection. It returns `HttpUrlConnection` hence unknown protocol exception is thrown.
What could be the reason behind it ?

It does not work in OnePlus2 device. This phone has OxygenOS version 3.5.5 and Android version 6.0.1

Comment: More information would help, here. Maybe include the rest of your methods code. Tell us on which devices this is not working and what versions of the Android API have not worked.

Comment: prepend `http://`  explicity in your string url if it does not have one.

Comment: Added the device details for which it is not working. Same code works in other devices.

Comment: Paste the whole exception. So that we can have more info

Comment: I am getting MalformedURLException
Detailed Message: Unknown Protocol: com.test.A.B

Answer (score 0):

url.openConnection() returns HttpURLConnection if your URL is a http:// URL, or HttpsURLConnection if your URL is a https:// URL.